# Any open-source file-viewer available on the net?

Tags: c#, java, viewer

Any of you knows if there is a open-source library in either Java or C# that can view files like Quick View Plus or Oracle Outside-In Viewer? I am currently working on a project where I index a lot documents with Lucene and Tika but I want to show the documents in there native form. I dot not prefer using the local installed programs like Word of Acrobat reader.

Thnx in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

C#

Log2Console is a development tool offering a nice UI to display, filter and search log messages from different logging services: Log4Net, Log4j and NLog. It can directly receive log events locally or remotely, or read them from a log file... It is written with C#.

http://log2console.codeplex.com/

Java

Chainsaw v2 is a companion application to Log4j written by members of the Log4j development community. Like a number of Open Source projects, this new version was built upon inspirations, ideas and creations of others. Chainsaw v2 has it's roots from the original Chainsaw utility written by Oliver Burn, and with inspiration from the Log Factor 5 utility contributed by ThoughtWorks Inc.

http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/index.html

Both Java & C#

TraceTool : A C#, C++, Delphi, ActiveX and Java trace framework and a trace viewer: Tail, outputDebugString, event log, and with Log4J, Log4Net, and Microsoft Enterprise Instrumentation Framework (EIF) support. This also comes with full support for Pocket PC development (C++ and DotNet).

http://tracetool.sourceforge.net/